# White Screen with Flutter: Rejected by Apple's App Review

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I am receiving this message with a rejection when I submit my app for review on the App Store:
"Specifically, your app displayed a white, blank screen when we launched your app."

When I test the app on device, everything appears to be working fine. I have tried the following to test:

1. `flutter build ios`
   `flutter run`
2. `flutter build ios --release`
   `flutter run`
3. Test with VSCode's run feature.
4. Run in xcode onto physical device both in Debug and Release schema settings
5. If I archive, and upload the same build to Testflight, the app can be installed and ran without issue on several different devices.

While all of these methods work on my physical iphone, when I run
`flutter build ios --release`
open xcode
archive
upload with Organizer in xcode

The app is rejected by Apple. I searched around and found nothing that solves my issues. Any suggestions or good next steps?

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/matthewkrager/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 days ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/matthewkrager/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    ✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Are you app have some high performing or network communication actions on startup?

Comment: take a look at this github issue, maybe it will help - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36247

Comment: Facing the same issue this week. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not a flutter dev, but, I received the same for my React Native app.
Did you resolve the issue btw?

Comment: Faced same issue in my 2 apps this week. Still clueless. Any update?